# How to detect current locale in Mac OS X from the shell

Tags: macos, locale

I need to detect the current locale in OS X from the command line. On Linux/Unix I can rely on LANG, but it is not always set:

http://henrik.nyh.se/2007/10/displaying-utf-8-correctly-in-leopard-terminal

I am looking for command line utilities or AppleScript code that allows me to find that information. Ideally they would work from 10.2 onwards

The closest I have found so far is

```
defaults read -g AppleLocale
```

which works on 10.3 onwards

Answer (score 15, accepted):

apropos yeilds the command `locale`

10.4 and later though

Edit:

```
defaults read .GlobalPreferences AppleLanguages | tr -d [:space:] | cut -c2-3
```

is mentioned [here](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24915). I don't have access to a 10.2 system though, so I don't know if it works.

Comment: Correct, I already ran across it but is only 10.4 and later, as you mention

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It does work in 10.2, but in returns English, whereas in the 10.3 and later returns the language code

Comment: thats odd, cut should make it always 2 characters

Comment: What I meant is that the language list in 10.2 is "English, French ..." whereas in 10.3 is "en, fr ..."

Comment: Found solution. See comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908180/know-currently-logged-in-users-language-in-mac-via-shell-script#comment21002995_14908268

Comment: In iTerm2 terminal , I can't run original command until I add **single quote** aside **[:space:]**

Answer (score 8):

```
locale
```

or if that's not disponible

```
env | grep LC_
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no LC_ are available either by default in many installs

Answer (score 0):

```
export LANG=$(defaults read -g AppleLanguages | \
  sed '/"/!d;s/["[:space:]]//g;s/-/_/').UTF-8
```

Comment: This will only work fine for a single language. When user has selected two preferred languages the resulting variable is incorrect, e.g. `en_GB, <new line>en_US`