# How to get the language of mac os through terminal

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I know language settings can be changed in the Language&Text window by mouse drag. But can I get the language info through the terminal, through a Python script, or through some other scripts?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661935/how-to-detect-current-locale-in-mac-os-x-from-the-shell

Comment: Great! Thank you!

>defaults read .GlobalPreferences AppleLanguages | tr -d [:space:] | cut -c2-3

Answer (score -1):

Open Terminal (located in /Applications/Utilities/).
Type or paste this command in Terminal:
sudo languagesetup
Press Return.
When prompted for a password, enter your account password and press Return again.  If your user has no password (a blank password) and you are using Mac OS X v10.5 or later, see sudo command requires a non-blank admin password.
A list of available languages will be displayed. Type the number that appears next to the language you want to use, then press Return.
Quit Terminal.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4102

Google first. ALWAYS!

Comment: >Thank you. And I have tried the above method,but only the login screen language be changed, the language of the system window after login is still ENU. And what I concerned about is how to get the language of the current system through the terminal, through a Python script, or through some other scripts?, rather than change it.