# Know currently logged in user's language in mac via shell script

Tags: macos, shell

what is the terminal command to know the user's language setting (language name is enough) in mac? Can you provide the shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a *list* of the user's language preferences with `defaults read NSGlobalDomain AppleLanguages`. OS X will use the languages in decreasing order of preference (if the first one is not available in a particular app). On my machine:

```
$ defaults read NSGlobalDomain AppleLanguages
(
    en,
    ja,
    fr,
    de,
    es,
    it,
    pt,
    "pt-PT",
    nl,
    sv,
    nb,
    da,
    fi,
    ru,
    pl,
    "zh-Hans",
    "zh-Hant",
    ko,
    ar,
    cs,
    hu,
    tr
)
```

In `bash`, to get the first one (the primary UI language), you can slice off the first one with this (admittedly messy) script:

```
 langs=(`defaults read NSGlobalDomain AppleLanguages`)
 echo ${langs[1]/,/} # langs[0] is the open bracket
```

Comment: hey , why does this not work with sudo ,, i mean         
sudo defaults read NSGlobalDomain AppleLanguages

Comment: You don't need sudo to use this.

Comment: yes, i agree but I am using this code in shell script which I execute with root permission. Is there any way out for the root user to know the language? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try using `sudo -u <username> ...` to execute a command as another user.

Comment: I did that,
If I use sudo -u $USER defaults read NSGlobalDomain AppleLanguages, It's again the same problem as USER is root(in the context explained above). But if I hard code the user, it runs fine. I don't want the script to be hardcoded for user. I know using 'users' command can return all the users but I need (dynamically) the name of user whose session is currently running and then pass this user in the command you explained above. How can I do this? I know I am very bad at scripts. Please bear with me.

Comment: If there is any command or code for that , can you please edit this in  your main answer above, so that it would be very helpful for me.

Comment: In my case I need `sudo -u $(loguser) ...`.